# How to setup auto complete alias for git commands?

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete

I was trying to create aliases like this:

```
alias '.a'='git add'
alias '.d'='git diff'
alias '.p'='git push'
alias '.f'='git fetch'
alias '.o'='git checkout'
alias '.c'='git commit -m'
alias '.b'='git branch'
alias '.s'='git status'
alias '.m'='git merge'
alias '.l'='git log -n 20 --oneline'
```

Autocompletion is always important, so I tried like this:

```
complete -F _git_checkout .o
```

But I got errors like after typing `<tab><tab>`:

```
#➤➤ .o bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

Then how can I make it work here?

---

My desktop runs on Ubuntu 13.04

---

@1, add a piece of code here where it seems failed on Ubuntu:

```
➤➤ complete | ack-grep alias
complete -F _alias_completion::grep grep
complete -F _alias_completion::la la
complete -F _alias_completion::ll ll
complete -F _alias_completion::l l
complete -F _alias_completion::ls ls
complete -a unalias
```

Comment: Which environment are you running this under?

Comment: @Cupcake it's Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Does [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/437508) from SU help?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers After adding this code, the error messages are gone. But the autocompletion for Git sub commands and branches are still missing.

Comment: While this question might also fit well at the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) and [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) sites, I feel that it is extremely useful for programmers who use Git as well. Are there disagreements with that statement?

Comment: @Cupcake I'm not so clear about the relationship among these three sites as my first language is not English. I agree with you, be free if there's anything you want to do.

Comment: With `complete -F _git_checkout go` you specify a completion only for the command `go`, which is none of the aliases you mentioned above.

Comment: @Armali I reproduced that problem on Ubuntu 13.04 server edition. Event running `go` gives the error.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by _event_? 2. Show your function `_git_checkout`. 3. What has this `go` to do with the aliases you mention at the start?

Comment: @Armali My mistake. I wrote "even running `go`".

Comment: 3. `go` is the one writtern in the guide, I changed `go` into `.g` in my case.

Comment: 2. I copied the file here: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6103999#file-git-bash-L888 since I don't read Bash I have no idea about how it works, could you help?

Comment: There is no alias `.g` defined in your question. For me with the alias completion code (pointed to by Ansgar Wiechers) `.o` seems to work, *without* defining extra completions like `complete -F _git_checkout go`. What does `complete` print?

Comment: @Armali Sorry about my mistake, it was '.o' not '.g'. But with `.o` it still gives error. I can find `complete -F _git_checkout .o` in the log which `complete` prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not define completions like `complete -F _git_checkout .o`.
Use the alias completion code (pointed to by Ansgar Wiechers above). After sourcing that script, completions like

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _alias_completion::.o .o
```

have been defined.

Comment: I found another problem of this. Your anwser helped me make it work, but on OS X, while there's still problem on Ubuntu. I pasted the output of `complete | ack-grep alias` above. And I've checked that both my aliases and the helper function are loaded. But the resposes to pressing tab twice are difference from each other.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487 Pasted some code here.. I loaded the `alias`es with the script in http://superuser.com/a/437508 , but the output of `complete` are different. The Ubuntu version doesn't contain my aliases such as `.g .a`.

Comment: Did you perhaps get the error about "too few X's" (mentioned in the *Troubleshooting* section)? Did you modify the said script (i. e. insert `XXX` in front of `.tmp` in line 16)?

Comment: Yes. How did you got to know that? I got that error and pasted the code that anwser gave, then no error again. Does that line matter?

Comment: I sensed it because I got this error, too. :-) When it occurs, the script apparently doesn't work right and the necessary completions are not defined. By "no error", do you mean that the completions are working now, or just that the error message is gone?

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say? - You could comment out the removal of the temporary file in the next-to-last line (`source "$tmp_file" # && rm -f "$tmp_file"`) and show this file (it should be like `/tmp/alias_completion-*.tmp`).

Comment: It's `4.2.37(1)-release`, while on Mac it's `3.2.48(1)-release`. I put that file at: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487#file-alias_completion-1749ekq-tmp

Comment: We see, the necessary completions here are not generated by the code script. Perhaps there's an incompatibility with bash 4.2; I'll try to get this bash version and test. Independently you could enter `set -x` before sourcing the code, and show the (possibly long) output thereof.

Comment: I pasted the code here: https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487#file-set-x-log

Comment: We can see in [set-x.log](https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487#file-set-x-log) at line 202 that the completion for `git` is missing, which according to [ubuntu.output](https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487#file-ubuntu-output), line 201 was between `/etc/init.d/irqbalance` and `p`. This incomplete list of completions is generated by the command `complete -p | sed -Ene '/complete( +[^ ]+)* -F ([^ ]+) ("[^"]+"|[^ ]+)/s//'\''\3'\''/p'`. (You could paste this command and append `| grep git` to verify.) From that, it looks like a bug in `sed` to me. Which version of `sed` do you have?

Comment: It's `4.2.1-10ubuntu1`, this one: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/sed . But I failed to get the version on OS X while it works fine.

Comment: I tried the Ubuntu version of `sed`, and it worked. If the completion for `git` really is there as shown in [ubuntu.output](https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/6218487#file-ubuntu-output) (you could verify with `complete|grep git`), then I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for an auto-completion solution specifically for a "git checkout" alias (gc, which is probably not a good alias) and came up with defining modifies the $COMP_WORDS and $COMP_CWORD variables:

```sh
# !/bin/sh

# Define a custom complete function for 'git checkout'.
___git_gco ()
{
    # Set the first word to git and insert checkout.
    COMP_WORDS=(git checkout ${COMP_WORDS[@]:1})
    # Increment the current word cursor, since we added one word.
    COMP_CWORD=$((COMP_CWORD + 1))

    # Show some debug information.
    # echo -n -e "\n${COMP_WORDS[0]}"
    # echo -n -e "\n${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
    # echo -n -e "\n${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
    # echo -n -e "\n${COMP_WORDS[@]}"

    # Call Git's default complete function.
    _git
}
# Define an alias for 'git checkout'.
alias gco="git checkout"
# Set the new alias to use the custom complete function.
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F ___git_gco gco
```

I don't know how good this solution is since it's messing with prepared by bash (there could be other variables supplied that I'm unaware of which might need modifications). It was tested only for the simplest case of checking out a branch without any options (although options do get completed).

Bottom line is - works for checking out a branch.